# gvim: List all options for guifont as text?

Tags: gvim, font

I know that I can use the GUI to navigate to the panel for setting `guifont`, and I can also issue `:set guifont=*`.

**Is there a way to list all options as text?**

I would like to capture them in a register using `:redir @a`, then paste them into a buffer and turn each one into a `set guifont` command:

```
set guifont=The\ first\ font
set guifont=The\ second\ font
set guifont=The\ third\ font
set guifont=The\ fourth\ font
     ... etc ...
```

It would them be simple to yank each one into register `"` and paste them into the command line.  Depending on what I see, I can re-order the list from best to last (or best smallest to best biggest).  I can retry each one as desired to refine the ordering.

**Current work-around**

My aim was to identify a series of fonts and sizes to which to map
 to .  My work-around is below.  I would still be
interested in whether there is a way to render into text all the font
names (family, weight, slant, size) in the `guifont` selection.

I manually transcribed the font family names from the selection
list for `guifont` into a text file, then added the font size and
vertical line spacing.  Comparably small fonts are:

```
Comparable small sizes of palatable font families
----------------------
set guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 8 linespace=0
set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 8 linespace=0
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 8 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0
```

I used the following test text to view the various fonts:

```
Test text
---------
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs
```

I then replicated each font enough times to perturb the font size
through a healthy range of sizes, truncating this range for fonts
that I didn't really like:

```
Step through sizes for each family
----------------------------------
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 10 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 11 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 12 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 13 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 14 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 15 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 16 linespace=0
set guifont=Consolas\ Regular\ 17 linespace=0

set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 8 linespace=0
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 10 linespace=0
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 11 linespace=0
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 12 linespace=0
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 13 linespace=0
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 14 linespace=0

set guifont=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 8 linespace=0
set guifont=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 10 linespace=0
set guifont=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 11 linespace=0
set guifont=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 12 linespace=0
set guifont=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 13 linespace=0
set guifont=Inconsolata\ Medium\ 14 linespace=0

set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 8 linespace=0
set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 10 linespace=0
set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 11 linespace=0
set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 12 linespace=0
set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 13 linespace=0
set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ Regular\ 14 linespace=0

setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0
setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 10 linespace=0
setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 11 linespace=0
setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 12 linespace=0
setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 13 linespace=0
setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 14 linespace=0
setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 15 linespace=0

set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 8 linespace=0
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 10 linespace=0
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 11 linespace=0
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 12 linespace=0
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 13 linespace=0
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 14 linespace=0

set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ Regular\ 10 linespace=0
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ Regular\ 11 linespace=0

set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ Medium\ 9 linespace=0
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ Medium\ 10 linespace=0
```

I liked `Lucida Console Regular` best through all the sizes,
including vertical spacing.  So in my vimrc, I created the following
mappings for quick font size switching:

```
    ... snip ...

elseif hostname() ==? "Name_of_laptop"

   map <C-F2> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 7.5 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F3> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 8 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F4> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 9 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F5> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 11 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F6> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 12 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F7> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 13 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F8> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 14 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F9> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 15 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F10> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 16 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F11> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 17 linespace=0<CR>
   map <C-F12> :setl guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 18 linespace=0<CR>
```

Comment: For the execution part, might be worth temporarily mapping something to `:exec getline('.')`

Comment: Thanks, D. Ben Knoble.